# Mavericks (OSx 10.9)program argument passing issue in py2app

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, py2app

The app that I built using **py2app** has a **program argument which is the file name**. For e.g a text file name that has to be opened using TextEdit. I did not cross check for other type of arguments. This app works fine in 10.8.5 OSx version but **fails to launch in 10.9 OSx** version. Few observations that may be useful to identify the fix - If we look at the open files in the Activity Monitor of this process then wee see that **'_*boot*_.py'** file is not opened in 10.9 but is open in 10.8.5 - If we directly run the python program (in a terminal) by navigating to the MacOS folder and providing the argument then the program runs fine.

My setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['myapp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
INCLUDE=['objc']
OPTIONS = {'iconfile':'cc.icns','includes':INCLUDE,'argv_emulation':True,'plist':{'CFBundleShortVersionString':'4.0.3','LSBackgroundOnly':True},}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the most recent version of py2app

Comment: Thanks for considering the issue. It is working fine with osx 10.9. One question, if app build in osx 10.9 using py2app, will work fine with previous version of osx like 10.8/10.7 or not with argument passing

Comment: It should work fine on older OSX versions as well, as long as you don’t use /usr/bin/python but a python build with support for older versions of OSX (such as the python.org installer)

Comment: that means I have to use /usr/local/bin/python setup.py py2app which will make complete standalone app and will run on all mac versions. And not use /usr/bin/python.